# Presenting ModalViewController turns the orientation of my app on start up

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to only support landscape.  There's a new requirement to show this dialog box that explains some things about our app the first time.  So in my first view controller that gets launched, in viewDidLoad, I have this code:

```
BOOL showFirstTimeUse = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShowFirstTimeUse"];
if (!showFirstTimeUse) {
    FirstUseViewController *tvc = [[FirstUseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstUseViewController" bundle:nil];
    tvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    tvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:tvc animated:YES];
    [tvc release];
}
```

Then in the FirstUseViewController, I have this defined:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

In IB, I have not changed any of the default settings.  I basically just dropped a UIWebView to the upper left hand side of the screen to show my data and connected an outlet to it so I can show formatted text easily.

When I run my app now, the presentation of this view controller causes my app to start in portrait rather than landscape.  How do I fix this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is faulty; It will always evaluate true. You likely want to use:

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
```